# group-policy shutdown script runs only on "Shutdown", not on "Reboot"

Tags: windows, reboot, group-policy, gpedit

I’ve configured GPEDIT to run a script at shutdown. But the script only works when I shutdown the system and does nothing when I restart the system.

Comment: Why are you expecting a script configured to run when the system is shut down to run when you restart the machine?  A hard reset (shutdown) and a soft reset (reset) are two entirely different events in Windows.

Comment: Are you able to set your script to run at Logoff?  If so that usually works for restart or shutdown (since both Logoff) .....   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789196(v=ws.11)

Comment: I just want the script to run. When a user shutdown or reboot the system. To save a state and finish some services. Without the need to instruct no one to do it manually. 
Yeah I’ve tried adding the script at log off.  But that didn’t worked. 
The script. It’s still running just during shutdown not restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run said script at *startup* instead? This would cover both types of events (i.e. shutdown and restart).

[image]

Alternatively use "When a spcific event is logged" and tie it to something that always runs, both at a cold boot and a reboot (for example Event ID 1074).

Comment: I’m not sure to understand that. 
But yeah I have a script to start some services but this script has been added to the task scheduler because its necessary for the script to run even if the user didn’t logon. And yeah that’s working as it should. 

But I don’t understand why isn’t working while restarting the system. 
I’m sure that I’ve done that before…

Comment: Could try to tie it to "when a specific event is logged" and then use one that will run both from a cold boot and a reboot perhaps :)

Comment: Ok thanks man. that did the trick, by creating a task when an specific event is logged was the best way to make it work. Just used the event ID 1074.

Comment: Great! It's a bit of a workaround I suppose, but I guess it works as intended. I'll update my post to include this :)